# ImportError: No module named pythoncom

Tags: python, django-mssql

I am a newbie (just 1 week) to this Python world. I tried installing django-mssql, but when I tried to import the library (using `import sqlserver_ado.dbapi`), I got this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named pythoncom
```

I tried to look for that library without success.

Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're on a Mac or Linux OS, use 'django-pyodbc' because django-mssql doesn't work

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are missing the `pythoncom` package. It comes with [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) but you can get it separately on [GitHub](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) (previously on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/)) as part of pywin32.

You can also simply use:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Comment: Let me try the ActivePython installation and will keep you posted, thnx

Comment: Installing ActivePython solved the hassle of installing other packages, it came with pretty much everything. Thnx once again

Comment: I think I just download Pywin32 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/. It works with the official Python distribution

Comment: I'm having this error on OSX Mavericks.  But I can't seem to be able to install pythoncom on mavericks.  What should I do?

Comment: That package is for Windows only. It uses Windows API and cannot be used on Mac.

Answer (score 15):

If you're on windows you probably want the `pywin32` library, which includes `pythoncom` and a whole lot of other stuff that is pretty standard.

Comment: And since installing pywin32 can give you headaches, try `pip install pypiwin32`

Answer (score 5):

You should be using [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install packages, since it gives you uninstall capabilities.

Also, look into [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). It works well with `pip` and gives you a sandbox so you can explore new stuff without accidentally hosing your system-wide install.

Comment: This is irrelevant answer. At best it could be a comment to another answer. not an answer on its own.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pip3 install pypiwin32
```

Sometimes using `pip3` also works if just `pip` by itself is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to cmd and install `pip install pywin32` pythoncom is part of pywin32 for API window extension....