# Setting up django-mssql issues

Tags: django, django-mssql

I'm having some issues setting up django-mssql on Win Server 2008 R2. I have everything installed, however, the wiki for django-mssql says to setup the settings file similar to:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2008',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
        'use_mars': True,
    },
   }
}
```

When I run from my site directory:

```
 python manage.py syncdb
```

I get an error stating it isn't an available database backend. When I installed django-mssql it seemed to install the backend here **\site-packages\django_mssql-1.0.1-py2.7.egg\sqlserver_ado** does this need to be copied to **site-packages\django\db\backends**?

I get the same error if I set my settings to:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'my_database',
    'ENGINE': 'django_mssql-1.0.1-py2.7.egg.sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': 'dbserver\\ss2008',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS' : {
        'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
        'use_mars': True,
    },
   }
}
```

Am I missing something when setting up this backend? This is my first time using django, but I didn't see anything in the documentation for setting up a different backend, and the django-mssql wiki or issues doesn't seem to have anything either.

Also, if there is other documentation somewhere that can help please let me know.

EDIT: The django app is running on Ubuntu server.

Comment: I would not copy external files into your Django directory. Not a good idea. But you probaly need to import the backend somewhere in your settings files. Maybe try `from mssql import *`?

Comment: When you decide to upgrade to Django 1.4, you'll need to update to django-mssql v1.1. `pip install django-mssql==1.1`

Comment: Thanks, glad they updated it to work with 1.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to make sure that you can import "sqlserver_ado" from your python shell.

Put the folder sqlserver_ado somewhere on your PATH, I put mine in \site-packages\

Take a look at the [README.txt](http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/source/browse/README.txt).

The engine does want to be set to "sqlserver_ado" similar to how the settings are done on the [settings sample page.](http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/wiki/Settings)

Comment: This seemed to do it...the documentation I had didn't have that tid-bit. Thanks.

Comment: One other thing for to consider is update to pywin32. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145079/importerror-no-module-named-pythoncom

Answer (score 6):

Dustin's comment about making sure "import sqlserver_ado" from the command shell got me going down the right path on my Django 1.8.1, Python 3.5 Win32 system with pywin32 installed.

***SPOILER ALERT*** This only gets my Django instance to run without errors.  I haven't tested the ADO connection yet.

The first error message I got was:

```
No module named 'django.db.backends.util'
```

and I found there is a file called: **django.db.backends.utils** so I copied it and renamed it to **django.db.backends.util** (without the 's') and away went the error message!

So hoping this wasn't too harmful, I continued on this line of troubleshooting.

The next error message I got was:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.db.backends import BaseDatabaseWrapper, BaseDatabaseFeatures, BaseDatabaseValidation, BaseDatabaseClient 
ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseDatabaseWrapper'
```

I changed line 7 in base.py to now say:

```
#from django.db.backends import BaseDatabaseWrapper, BaseDatabaseFeatures, BaseDatabaseValidation, BaseDatabaseClient
from django.db.backends.base.base import BaseDatabaseWrapper
from django.db.backends.base.features import BaseDatabaseFeatures
from django.db.backends.base.validation import BaseDatabaseValidation
from django.db.backends.base.client import BaseDatabaseClient
```

Yes, that's commenting out the bad line and adding four separate lines.
Then I got this error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 18, in <module>
from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\introspection.py", line 3, in 
    from django.db.backends import BaseDatabaseIntrospection 
    ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseDatabaseIntrospection'

so I changed the line 3 to now read:

```
from django.db.backends.base.introspection import BaseDatabaseIntrospection
```

and so on for creation.py:

```
from django.db.backends.base.creation import BaseDatabaseCreation
```

for operations.py:

```
from django.db.backends.base.operations import BaseDatabaseOperations
```

for schema.py:

```
from django.utils.log import getLogger
```

Hope this helps someone.  Hope the ADO module actually connects to something.

-Sean

Comment: Just had this exact same issue. Fresh install of django, pywin32 and django-mssql and I've fell at the first hurdle.Is this a bug? I am using python 2.7

Comment: `from logging import getLogger` did the job on the last part

Answer (score 3):

**As of 2019:**

I couldn't get Django MSSQL to work at all.

I switched over to [django-pyodbc-azure](https://pypi.org/project/django-pyodbc-azure/) and that works great.

Install:

```
pip install django-pyodbc-azure
```

Setup:

```
'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc'
```

Comment: This uses djang<=2.1

Comment: I was running Django 3.1.7 and installing django-pyodbc-azure caused it downgrade to Django 2.1.15 which made other code break. I had to "pip install Django=3.1.7" to recover.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the dependency PyWin32.  You can install via pip or download from the python binaries page http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Sorry, this wasn't mentioned above but the django app is running on Ubuntu. So the PyWin32 wont install.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get django_pyodbc to work, and couldn't. I was getting this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseWrapper
```

I was [directed to this post as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051839/using-sql-server-on-django/30181063#comment48218347_30051839), so I'll post my answer here also.
I downgraded to django 1.6 instead of 1.8, and now django_pyodbc works as a database backend.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc/pull/96, django_pyodbc should now work with Django 1.8. So this seems to be a good alternative to django-mssql for those requiring SQL Server 2008 R2 support.