# How can I connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 with django-mssql?

Tags: django, sql-server-2008, django-mssql, django-pyodbc

I cannot figure out why I cannot get django to connect with sql server 2008 r2. I have administrative privileges on our server and on sql server. I have constructed a virtual windows box with windows server 2008 sp2 because I thought I might have some luck with django-mssql. I've tried both django-pyodbc and django-mssql on the windows box but have not yet succeeded. Here are my db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',  # Have also tried sql_server.pyodbc
        'NAME': 'TMSEPLAY',                      
        'USER': '***', # Omitted for post
        'PASSWORD': '*******', # Omitted for post
        'HOST': '172.16.1.14',                      
        'PORT': '1434',                   
        'OPTIONS': {
            'provider': 'SQLCLI10', # Have also tried 'SQLCLI11' and 'SQLOLEDB'
            'extra_params': 'DataTypeCompatibility=80'
            }
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
C:\Python27\CourseData\mysite>manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\CourseData\mysite\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 306,
 in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 193, in _curs
or
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 168, in __con
nect
    use_transactions=self.use_transactions,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py", line 151, in conn
ect
    raise OperationalError(e, "Error opening connection: " + connection_string)
sqlserver_ado.dbapi.OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurre
d.', (0, u'ADODB.Connection', u'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly
 installed.', u'C:\\Windows\\HELP\\ADO270.CHM', 1240655, -2146824582), None), 'E
rror opening connection: DATA SOURCE=172.16.1.14,1434;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;I
nitial Catalog=TMSEPLAY;UID=***;PWD=********;PROVIDER=SQLCLI10;MARS Connection=Tr
ue;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True')
```

I'd appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see an error message in that log:

$Error opening connection: DATA SOURCE=172.16.1.14 port:1434

So I would see if all instances are running and is accessible on that machine through port 1434.

Also, the following may help:
[Setting up django-mssql issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944204/setting-up-django-mssql-issues?rq=1)

Comment: Hari, Thanks so much! I searched the registry of SQL Server for "SuperSocketNetLib" under Microsoft SQL Server and opened TCP. It turns out that the Admin Connection TCP port is 1434, but the non-admin ports are all 1433. I finally got in using 'SQLOLEDB' as 'provider'. Thanks a million!

Comment: I would also look at this question, as it addresses same original error message (Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly
 installed.): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967989/django-giving-error-exception-typeoperationalerror/22985901#comment54235850_22985901