# Django giving error: Exception Type: OperationalError

Tags: django, python-2.7

Exception Value:

```
(com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', 
 (0, 
  u'ADODB.Connection',
  u'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.', 
  u'C:\\Windows\\HELP\\ADO270.CHM', 1240655, -2146824582),
  None),
 u'Error opening connection: DATA SOURCE=172.16.26.51\\myinstance;Initial Catalog=dbName;UID=****;PWD=****;PROVIDER=sqlncli10;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True')
```

I am using:

```
Django==1.5.5
django-mssql==1.4
pywin32==218
```

Same project with same setup, runs on successfully on one machine but it doesn't run other machine.

I used PIP for installation of Django and django-mssql.

here is Traceback

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\newsite\dbexplorer\views.py" in viewVersionList
  18.     cursor = connection.cursor()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py" in cursor
  324.             cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py" in _cursor
  241.             self.__connect()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py" in __connect
  196.             use_transactions=self.use_transactions,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\dbapi.py" in connect
  151.         raise OperationalError(e, "Error opening connection: " + connection_string)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /dbexplorer/
Exception Value: (com_error(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'ADODB.Connection', u'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.', u'C:\\Windows\\HELP\\ADO270.CHM', 1240655, -2146824582), None), u'Error opening connection: DATA SOURCE=172.16.26.51\\myinstance;Initial Catalog=dbexplorer;UID=****;PWD=****;PROVIDER=sqlncli10;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This errors comes because some of my machine don't have SQL Native client installed.

You can download it from [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30440)

You can get a stand alone installer for the client. Download installer according to your architecture.

Select one of them :`sqlncli_x86.msi`/`sqlncli_ia64.msi`/`sqlncli_amd64.msi`

Comment: If you have this issue on newer versions: django-mssql v1.7 still requires SQL Native Client 10, and newer versions of the SQL server (2012 and above) ship with 11. So you need to download the older client even when you have the newer one installed. Fortunately, this is not a problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131321.aspx and you can get it here: http://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/installing-sql-server-native-client-10-0 or here: http://serverfault.com/questions/506490/how-do-i-install-sql-svr-native-client-10-1-after-sql-2012-has-been-installed

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this ([Establishing connection to MS SQL Server 2014 with django-mssql-1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406943/establishing-connection-to-ms-sql-server-2014-with-django-mssql-1-6)
) helped me with the same issue:

Changing the settings for Databases to include the 'provider' option and setting that to 'SQLOLEDB'

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'CVH_Dev',
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': '192.***.212.2**',
    'USER': 'USER',
    'PASSWORD': 'PWD',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
        'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's saying it can't get to your database. The database may only be allowing access from certain machines.

This isn't an error from Django; it's from the `sqlserver_ado` Python module you have installed. Check its documentation for a "Provider cannot be found" error.

Comment: database can be access from any where.. I tried to connect it sql server management studio and php. it works.

Comment: Then the most likely thing is that the `sqlserver_ado` Python module is not properly installed.

Comment: This errors comes because some of my machine don't have SQL Native client installed. Thanks for your help :)