# Unable to connect to MSSQL database via django-mssql

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-mssql

I'm trying to connect to my Microsoft SQL Server database from django but I am getting the following error when running the web server using [django-mssql](http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)

```
PS N:\Documents\Python> python .\manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 135, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name getLogger
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'Misc',
        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
        'HOST': 'server1\\ss2012',
        'USER': 'DOMAIN\dcullen',
        'PASSWORD': 'X',
    }
}
```

I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944204/setting-up-django-mssql-issues/36977622#36977622) post to solve the issue but it fails on the `getLogger` part at the bottom.

What could the issue be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getLogger` alias was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/13bc311cdb11e590acf8942540d7db518d8082f9), so the following import will fail in Django 1.9

```
from django.utils.log import getLogger
```

I think you should be able to import `getLogger` from the Python module directly.

```
from logging import getLogger
```