# Import pythoncom error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pythoncom

I am using python version 3.6.1 and my operating system is Windows 10
My code is not working and I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in
<module>
     import pythoncom   File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py",
 line 2, in <module>
     import pywintypes   File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py",
 line 127, in <module>
     __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())   File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py",
 line 114, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
     mod = imp.load_dynamic(modname, found)   File "C:\Users\Egypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\imp.py",
 line 342, in load_dynamic
     return _load(spec)
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Please help me to Complete my first script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when i try import pythoncom i get this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890464/when-i-try-import-pythoncom-i-get-this-error)

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145079/importerror-no-module-named-pythoncom