# name 'pythoncom' is not defined

Tags: python, com

I had read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145079/importerror-no-module-named-pythoncom) and installed pywin32 from [this place](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases), both Python27 and Python36.

However I got the error. I don't know why. I tried both Python27 and Python36. The errors are identical.

[image]

To be more detailed, I put my sample code below:

```
 import win32com.client
 from win32com.client import constants, DispatchBaseClass, CastTo, VARIANT
 import sys

 mode = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BSTR | pythoncom.VT_BYREF, "")
```

Result after delete the old Python, reinstalled both ActivePython 3.6 and pywin32com package. Screen shot like below:

[image]

Is there any workaround which needn't use the pythoncom?

Comment: Did you install ActivePython as suggested in the accepted answer in the thread you mentioned?

Comment: After reading your comment, I deleted the original python and reinstall an ActivePython3.6, then reinstalled pywin32com, but no lucky. I'm trying ActivePython2.7...

Comment: for your own good install linux

Answer (score 0):

Install pywin32.
Copy the files from pywin32_system32 path to win32