# pyttsx3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythoncom'

Tags: python, python-3.x

in `pyttsx3` i have the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythoncom'
```

i don't know what to do pls tell

[the Error code print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdIpY.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named pythoncom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145079/importerror-no-module-named-pythoncom)

Answer (score 2):

Just run the following command:

```
pip install pywin32
```

The `pythoncom` package is missing. It's built in the standard of [ActivePython](https://www.activestate.com/products/python/) but you can get it on [Github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) as pywin32.

Answer (score 0):

From the image you've provided, I can see that you're using a Windows OS. This link might help: [ImportError: No module named pythoncom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145079/importerror-no-module-named-pythoncom)

It suggests you install the pywin32 package using the following command:

```
pip install pywin32
```